# During which actions is AWS Cognito Lambda `Pre-signup` invoked?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

There is some ambiguity in the docs...

[These docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) seem to imply that `pre-signup` is called only during signup and first-time (?) external provider login. The only *trigger source* constants mentioned are:

- PreSignUp_SignUp
- PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser
- PreSignUp_ExternalProvider

However, the [ForgotPassword doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html) mentions calling it as well:

> When you use the ForgotPassword API action, Amazon Cognito invokes any functions that are assigned to the following triggers: pre sign-up, custom message, and user migration.

In general is there a definitive, accurate source of what Cognito Lambdas are called for which user/api actions?

Answer (score 2):

Below is AWS's response to my comment on their docs page. In short **pre-sign-up is NOT run on ForgotPassword**.

> We recently received feedback from you about the following page in the
> Cognito documentation:
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html
>
> Your comments were:
>
> What I'm trying to do: ...
>
> What to make better: Does InitiateAuth trigger pre-signup? Its a bit
> ambiguous in the ClientMetadata section. Really each of these docs
> should have a section on lambdas invoked or better, a chart of how and
> when (for instance, ForgetPW is a three part process - when are the
> various lambdas invoked??)
>
> I'm sorry that you're having difficulty finding the information you
> need. **The sources for Pre sign-up triggers are listed at link [1]. The
> function runs when you run the SignUp and AdminCreateUser APIs, as
> well as when you sign in for the first time using an external
> provider.** The triggers that you can run on InitiateAuth are Pre
> Authentication, Post authentication, Define/Create/Verify custom auth,
> pre token generation, custom message, and migrate user.
>
> Link [1] also describes the triggers associated with a **ForgotPassword
> process. You can run post confirmation, pre token, migrate user, and
> custom message functions.**
>
> Thanks for taking the time to send us feedback! We appreciate all
> feedback, whether it's positive or it alerts us to a problem we need
> to address. Please don't hesitate to contact us with any other
> feedback you might have about our documentation.
>
> [1] Customizing user pool workflows with Lambda triggers - User pool Lambda trigger sources - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-trigger-sources